# Customized links for translated navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, modern-experience, quick-launch, anchor-tags

Since the update which allows for direct translation of the navigation, rather than the old method based upon language settings of the editor, it seems no longer possible to use a different link for the translated item.

This is fairly inconvenient if sites are strongly based upon anchors that you link to in your navigation.

Is there any way in which we can still alter the links for a translated version of the navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, currently there is no way to provide multiple Address/URLs for a single navigation link.

For more information, check below documentations:

1. [Create multilingual communication sites, pages, and news](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-multilingual-communication-sites-pages-and-news-2bb7d610-5453-41c6-a0e8-6f40b3ed750c)
2. [Set up a multilingual site name, navigation and footer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-multilingual-communication-sites-pages-and-news-2bb7d610-5453-41c6-a0e8-6f40b3ed750c#bkmk_muitranslations)